# Call center dispatch using object-oriented Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I am looking for tips on improving my implementation of an OOP design problem in Python3

Here is the problem (paraphrasing to save space):

There is a call center with three levels of employees - Respondent, Manager and Director. 
A call that goes to the center propagates as Respondent -> Manager -> Director depending on whether or not

a) The respondent is free and can handle the call

b) The manager is free and can handle the call

The call center needs to have a dispatchCall() method that assigns the call to the first available employee

Here is the code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from random import random

class CallCenter():
    """
    A call center class that will be inherited from by the director

    Attributes:
        name: Name of the employee
        number: Mobile phone number of the employee
        level: Define level of the employee - respondent, manager or director
    """
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, name, number, level):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.level = level

    def canEmployeeHandle(self):
        canHandle = random()
        if canHandle > 0.5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isEmployeeBusy(self):
        busy = True if random() <= 0.5 else False
        return busy

    @staticmethod
    def dispatchCall():
        return respondent.answerCall()

    @abstractmethod
    def answerCall(self):
        """Print a string indicating that this employee is currently
        answering the call or propogate up the chain"""
        pass

class Director(CallCenter):
    """
    A class definition for the director who will be the third in chain
    to answer the call
    """
    def answerCall(self):
        print("The director is now on call with you")


class Manager(Director):
    """
    A class definition for the manager who will be the second in chain to
    answer the call
    """
    def answerCall(self):
        if not self.isEmployeeBusy() and self.canEmployeeHandle():
            print("The manager is answering your call")
        else:
            super(Manager, self).answerCall()

class Respondent(Manager):
    canHandle = random() #class variable to check if respondent can handle call
    """
    A class definition for the respondent who will be the first in chain
    to answer the call
    """
    def answerCall(self):
        if not self.isEmployeeBusy() and self.canEmployeeHandle():
            print("The respondent is answering your call")
        else:
            super(Respondent, self).answerCall()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    director = Director("Alex", "+17654736791", "director")
    manager = Manager("Unai", "+331577285782", "manager")
    respondent = Respondent("Mark", "+16574872817", "respondent")

    CallCenter.dispatchCall()
```

Comment: "A call center class that will be inherited from by the manager" Are you sure that's what you're doing here?

Comment: @Mast - Yeah, sorry that was supposed to read inherited from by the director. I've updated it

Comment: Is it possible to be a director and a manager, or respondent and a manager, at the same time?

Comment: @Peilonrayz - No, those three are mutually exclusive roles

Answer (score 2):

Segragated the responsilibites of call center into call center and employee

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from random import random


class CallCenter(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """
    A call center class that will be inherited from by the director

    Attributes:
        name: Name of the employee
        number: Mobile phone number of the employee
        level: Define level of the employee - respondent, manager or director
    """

    @classmethod
    def dispatchCall(self, cls):
        return cls.answerCall()


class Employee(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, name, number, level):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.level = level

    def canEmployeeHandle(self):
        canHandle = random()
        if canHandle > 0.5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isEmployeeBusy(self):
        busy = True if random() <= 0.5 else False
        return busy


    @abstractmethod
    def answerCall(self):
        """Print a string indicating that this employee is currently
        answering the call or propogate up the chain"""
        pass



class Director(Employee):
    """
    A class definition for the director who will be the third in chain
    to answer the call
    """

    def answerCall(self):
        print("The director is now on call with you")


class Manager(Director):
    """
    A class definition for the manager who will be the second in chain to
    answer the call
    """

    def answerCall(self):
        if not self.isEmployeeBusy() and self.canEmployeeHandle():
            print("The manager is answering your call")
        else:
            print("Manager is busy, escalating the call to the Director")
            super(Manager, self).answerCall()


class Respondent(Manager):
    canHandle = random()  # class variable to check if respondent can handle call
    """
    A class definition for the respondent who will be the first in chain
    to answer the call
    """

    def answerCall(self):
        if not self.isEmployeeBusy() and self.canEmployeeHandle():
            print("The respondent is answering your call")
        else:
            print("Employee is busy, escalating the call to the Manager")
            super(Respondent, self).answerCall()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    director = Director("Alex", "+17654736791", "director")
    manager = Manager("Unai", "+331577285782", "manager")
    respondent = Respondent("Mark", "+16574872817", "respondent")
    CallCenter.dispatchCall(respondent)
    enter code here
```